# Scan a file to search pre-defined c keywords and print them on console

Tags: c

How can I scan a file for a word and then print the line containing that word in C programming?

I am trying to find a way to scan a file for a keyword and then print only the line containing that word. I am off to a very rough start. Here is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getDsk (void);

void getDsk ()
{
FILE* fp;
char result [1000];
fp = popen("diskutil list","r");
fread(result,1,sizeof(result),fp);
fclose (fp);

while(!feof(fp)) {
        if(//line contains "Test".)
        {
            //show line.
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    getDsk();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** This did what I needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getDsk (void);

void getDsk ()
{
    printf("Your available Windows installations are:\n");
    FILE* fp = popen("diskutil list","r");
    char line[1024];
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) 
    {
        if (strstr(line,"Microsoft")) 
        {
            printf("%s", line);
        }
        // if line contains the text, print it
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    getDsk();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you stuck somewhere? How can we help?

Comment: Yes in the while statement. I put //comments where I am having trouble.

Comment: What are you stuck *on*? How to detect whether a particular string contains another string? How to iterate over CR-separated strings in a file? Be specific.

Comment: I want to get information from os x diskutil and print out all the lines that contain the word "microsoft". Or if you know of a better strategy to find ntfs partitions, more specifically windows installations.

Comment: I want to detect if a FILE contains a string, if so, print out the line that contains that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1) You should pretty much never write `while(!feof(fp)) { ... }` It is a **broken** pattern because `feof` will only return true **after** a read attempt. So you are open to off by one errors.

2) why the heck are you doing this?

```
fp = popen("diskutil list","r");
fread(result,1,sizeof(result),fp);
fclose (fp);
```

You are reading `1000` chars of the file then **closing** it, then later your stub code acts as if it plans on reading the file some more... makes no sense.

3) here's a reasonable approach:

```
char line[1024];
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    // if line contains the text, print it
}
```

what is going on here is `fgets` will read a line and return non-`NULL` if it succeeds. (`NULL` is treated as "false", non-`NULL` is "true" when used in a test).

So it is saying "while we could successfully read a line, do the following", which is really what you want. Also, I am making the assumption that no lines will exceed `1024` characters which is usually a reasonable assumption, if this is not the case, then you will need to adjust accordingly.

Comment: The code you asked about runs a command and then if i decide to use fprint i can display what that command returns from the system. But I do see how it can seem useless for my purposes. I had that at first to read the whole file.

Comment: How might i code "if line contains text print it" I want to print the entire line.

Comment: @arynhard: i suggest you study the language more, look at the documentation for `strstr`. This is a **trivial** task

Comment: @arynhard:   We've given you about 95% of the code.   If you cannot figure out the last little bit (how to print a line), you may have bigger issues.  This is not a "write my code for me" kind of place.

Comment: I know how to print stuff. What I don't understand is how to print a SPECIFIC line from a file.

Comment: @arynhard:   See my answer. It is just "puts(line);"  DUH.

Comment: @EvanTeran: thank you for your help. Pointing me in the right direction is more helpful than just telling me to learn more.

Comment: @arynhard: no problem. Everyone is a beginner at some point. Just do you best to follow the advice of people on the site. While they are unlikely to spell out answers, they will pretty much always give you the tools needed to discover the answer on your own (which is a much more powerful learning tool). I highly recommend you familiarize yourself with the standard library (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ is a good enough reference, not perfect but enough to learn the core stuff from).

Comment: @EvanTeran: See my edit. Is this what you were pointing me to? Seems to work.

Comment: @arynhard: looks like a reasonable implementation. Good job. Don't forget to `fclose` the `FILE*` though!

Answer (score 3):

In your current code, it looks like you're reading the entire file at once into `result`, so there is no concept of a "line".

I recommend changing your loop so you read the file one line at a time.
Investigate [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/).
On each line, check that line for the keyword ([strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/)).

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    if (strstr(line, keyword) != NULL) {
        puts(line);   // if line contains the text, print it
    }
}
```

Comment: He is using `popen` because `diskutil` is a program, not a file...