# How can I scan a file for a word and then print the line containing that word in another file in C programming?

Tags: c, file-io

How can I scan a file for a word and then print the line containing that word in another file in C programming?

```
META_FILE = fopen("vs2008.map","r");
fp=fopen("META_DATA_INFO","w");


while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), META_FILE)) 
{
    if (strstr(line,"0004:") != NULL) 
    {
        puts(line,fp); // this line print on screen i want a function to write in fp file   
        }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902950/scan-a-file-for-a-keyword-and-print-matching-lines?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Change `puts(line, fp);` to one of:

```
fputs(line, fp); // note: this does not write a newline
```

or:

```
fprintf(fp, "%s\n", line); // this writes a newline
```

Comment: Suggest dropping the `'\n'` from `"%s\n"`.  `line` likely already ends with a `'\n'` and is redundant.  `fputs(line, fp);` very likely _does_ write a newline - from the string `line`.  That function does not perform special filtering to not write a newline.  `fputs()` does not append a  `'\n'` like `puts(line,fp)`.